# Jenkins docker setup

Tags: jenkins, docker, build, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to make build of project, but now my client wants to make builds inside of a Docker image. i have installed docker on server and its running on `172.0.0.1:PORT`. I have installed Docker plugin and assigned this TCP URL to Docker URL. I have also created an image with the name jenkins-1
In configure project I use Build environment `Build with Docker Container` and provide image name. and then in Build in put `Execute Shell` and then Build it

But it gives the Error:

```
Pull Docker image jenkins-1 from repository ...`
 $ docker pull jenkins-1`
 Failed to pull Docker image jenkins-1`
 FATAL: Failed to pull Docker image jenkins-1`
 java.io.IOException: Failed to pull Docker image jenkins-1``
  at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.PullDockerImageSelector.prepare DockerImage(PullDockerImageSelector.java:34)`
 at   com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerBuildWrapper.setUp(DockerB`uildWrapper.java:169)`
 at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)`
 at `hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)`
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)`
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)`
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)`
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)`
 Finished: FAILURE`
```

[image]

Comment: image jenkins-1 doesnt exist!

Comment: No offense, but do you really understand what you're trying to achieve? Have you managed to implement same thing (i.e. build within docker container) manually, not driven by Jenkins?

Comment: added screenshot in queston. jenkins-1 exixt @yashpandey

Comment: Can you try the official Jenkins image first? ```docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just have run into the same issue. There is a 'Verbose' check-box in the configuration of build environment after selecting 'Advanced...' link to expand on the error details:

[CloudBees plug-in Verbose option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxnBc.png)

In my case I ran out of space downloading the build Docker images. Expanding ec2 volume has resolved the issue.

But there is an ongoing trouble with space as docker does not auto cleans images and I have ended up adding a manual cleanup step into the build:

`docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm`

Complete build script:

https://bitbucket.org/vk-smith/dotnetcore-api/src/master/ci-build.sh?fileviewer=file-view-default